# Null is not an object imagepickerManager.launchCamera

Tags: ios, image, react-native

I'm struggling to find the good function with the new version of image picker.

i just wanna be able to pick a picture or take picture from the app.

My function :

```
function App (){
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        },
        button: {
          marginVertical: 24,
          marginHorizontal: 24,
        },
        image: {
          marginVertical: 24,
          alignItems: 'center',
        },
        response: {
          marginVertical: 16,
          marginHorizontal: 8,
        },
      });
    const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
          <ScrollView>
            <Button
              title="Take image"
              onPress={() =>
                ImagePicker.launchCamera(
                  {
                    mediaType: 'photo',
                    includeBase64: false,
                    maxHeight: 200,
                    maxWidth: 200,
                  },
                  (response) => {
                    setResponse(response);
                  },
                )
              }
            />
             <View style={styles.response}>
          <Text>Res: {JSON.stringify(response)}</Text>
        </View>

        {response && (
          <View style={styles.image}>
            <Image
              style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
              source={{uri: response.uri}}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

also my error :

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.ImagePickerManager.launchCamera')

Comment: Did you link a native dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with your linking for the library.

Note : Make sure you are on version 3.x.x and to clean the cache

Steps to install

1. npm install react-native-image-picker
2. npx react-native run-android

And then use the launchCamera like

`import {launchCamera} from 'react-native-image-picker'`

Then `launchCamera(options?, callback);`